# DynamoDb querying with geo-spatial data (Local Secondary Index) AND foreign keys saved as range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm trying to construct a DynamoDb table supporting these 3 access patterns:

1. Access list of institutions within XX radius of a given zip code.
2. Access list of institutions within XX radius of a given zip code for a given education level (4-year, 2-year, high school, etc).
3. Access list of institutions within XX radius of a given zip code for a given job code and education level.

The Partition Key is generated as part of the Geo Library for DynamoDb ([AWS Geo Library)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb/).  So basically, I'm grouping institutions together by geo-location supporting the ability to search for institutions within XX radius of a supplied zip code (using zip code's lat/lon).

Below is my CloudFormation template for my DynamoDb table:

```
    dynamoDbInstitutions:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
        TableName: institutions
        AttributeDefinitions:
            - AttributeName: hashKey
              AttributeType: N
            - AttributeName: rangeKey
              AttributeType: S
            - AttributeName: geohash
              AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: hashKey
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: rangeKey
              KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput: 
            ReadCapacityUnits: 50
            WriteCapacityUnits: 2
        LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: geohash-index
          KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: hashKey
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: geohash
            KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
```

Here's an example of data in my table:

[image]

- ***176008*** represents an institution.
- ***2*** represents education level (4-year institution).
- ***11-1011.00*** represents a job code

Hashkey value 966762 is the first 6 digits from GeoHash value.  This allows me to group institutions together by proximity.  This allows me to search for institutions within a radius.  I have a Local Secondary Index (LSI) using Hashkey and GeoHash.  My query is using LSI to find institutions within a radius.

I'm wanting to also be able to further filter institutions within the radius by these access patterns:

- **education level**.  Example:  2_*
- **job code and education level**.  Example: 11-1011.00_2_*

I've run into a wall where DynamoDb only allows querying based on 2 key conditions.  In order to do geo querying (within a radius), I have to use hash key and LSI (using geohash).  I'm prevented from further filtering using my range key which is modeling relationships an institution has with education level and job codes.

How do I use DynamoDb to filter by radius **AND** filter using related data like education level and/or job code?

Comment: Since this is an old question. Have you actually figured this out? I am kinda in the same situation as you were.